# Scramble and descramble file at commandline

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-line-interface

I want to send a helping executable to a customer, but the email filtering is quiet hard to trick. I tried the following:

- encrypted zipping,
- change the filename extension and
- adding four random bytes at the beginning of the file

but the file was blocked anyway. :-(

Now I want to scramble the file, send it to him and he descrambles it. Scrambling could mean:

- XOR
- NOT
- Rot128 (like Rot13)
- ... (I'm open for suggestions)

I can't send a descrambling executable to the customer, but he can use the command line.

Scrambling does not necessarily have to be at command line, but is there a way to descramble a file from command line?

Comment: Could the downvoter please comment his action?

Answer (score 0):

First off: sending an executable generally isn't a great idea, because executables (aside from some special setup ones) are mostly already compiled, machine language programms, which means an executable running on your machine might produce fatal errors on another machine, as they may have entirely different machine languages and API's.

But, thats not wat you asked, so i'm gonna go on.

Well, purely relying on the command line here is not going to bring you much further than encrypted zipping, so i personally would suggest you create and compile something in a farely low-level language (like my favourite, c++) which can be run from the command line with the filename as argument and will XOR your file with a random number string generated form a key.

I could post code that does that right here.

but since your customer probably has no compiler and no clue how to compile a c++ file, and since his mail filter is that restrictive that it might also filter out c++ files that can be made into something suspicios (e.g. a decryptor described above), this also isn't an option.

The problem with using the command line to manipulate files directly (as to "scramble" and "unscramble" them) is that it is really crappy, which means that unexpected input (like "&%^^@~&* )is almost certainly going to mess with your batch programm, as commands and variables are not properly seperated.

So unless you are extremely lucky and none of these characters are present in your file you wont be able to properly do any action on them.

I am farely out of ideas how you could possibly solve this problem only by using the command line, but if you are willing to try out the c++ approach just tell me that, and we can go on.

hammockdude out

Answer (score 0):

I know, very old thread, but there is a solution which does not require any programming at all while all involved tools are almost always present on any Linux installation - by base64-encoding the file and reversing the resulting text lines. This works in most cases:

base64 <binary file> | rev > <binary file>.txt

The receiver just needs to do the opposite:

rev <binary file>.txt | base64 -id > <binary file>

I would recommend to accompany the text file with an sha-256 hash of the original file so that the receiver can verify the correctness of the decoded file.

Additional hint for the unlikely event that the mail scanner still doesn't like it: in one case adding random spaces to each line through an awk script thereby creating a look akin to text with words brought that last barrier down as well.

Please allow me to add to hammockdude's warning that not only is a binary not always executable on another host, e.g. when running it on a different distro than where it had been created, it can also land you in very hot water if you get caught in environments where doing things like this has been explicitly forbidden. So, please tread with care.